# Ubuntu 13.04 cannot connect via WiFi but can connect to HotSpot created with Android

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I've just bought a new computer (Lenovo G580) and installed Ubuntu 13.04. I can't connect via Wi-Fi, only via cable.

I've tried with several networks (mine and my neighbors) but nothing, and then the weird part comes: when creating a hotspot with my Android device I was able to connect to Internet. I am a bit confused!

Does anybody knows what may be happening or how to solve it?

Maybe this data is useful:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

If you need any further data please ask, I will try to answer ASAP.

PD: before installing Ubuntu 13.04 I was using an old computer with Ubuntu 12.04 and WiFi worked just fine.

PD2: I have tried with several WiFi connections, mine and 3 neighbors, but we all have in common the same ISP.

edit:

result of running 'grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | tail -30' while connected to the Android hotspot:

```
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$ grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | tail -30
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'pakete207'.
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2676
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> bound
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   address 192.168.43.88
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   gateway 192.168.43.1
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   hostname 'pakete207-G580'
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.43.1'
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 28 11:20:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 28 11:20:12 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Apr 28 11:20:12 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 28 11:20:12 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 28 11:20:12 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Policy set 'pakete207' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 28 11:20:12 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 11:20:12 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) successful, device activated.
Apr 28 11:20:32 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth1): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 28 11:20:32 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 28 11:20:32 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 28 11:20:32 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$
```

result while trying to connect to the domestic network (not possible to connect):

```
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$ grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | tail -60
Apr 28 12:00:01 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.1
Apr 28 12:00:01 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Apr 28 12:00:01 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info>   domain name 'localdomain'
Apr 28 12:00:01 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 28 12:00:01 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 28 12:00:02 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Apr 28 12:00:02 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 28 12:00:02 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 28 12:00:02 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Policy set 'Conexión cableada 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 28 12:00:02 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 12:00:02 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Apr 28 12:00:21 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 28 12:00:21 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 28 12:00:21 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 28 12:00:21 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 28 12:01:37 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested') [100 30 39]
Apr 28 12:01:37 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'user-requested') [39]
Apr 28 12:01:37 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 8923
Apr 28 12:01:37 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Apr 28 12:01:37 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) starting connection 'ALICE-WLAN84 1'
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless): access point 'ALICE-WLAN84 1' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless): connection 'ALICE-WLAN84 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'ALICE-WLAN84'
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 28 12:01:46 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 28 12:01:48 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'ALICE-WLAN84'.
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> dhclient started with pid 9062
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 28 12:01:49 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$
```

Result of the test while connected to the domestic network (not via WiFi):

```
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$ grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | tail -30
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> dhclient started with pid 3117
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   address 192.168.1.232
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.1
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info>   domain name 'localdomain'
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 28 11:30:50 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 28 11:30:51 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Apr 28 11:30:51 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 28 11:30:51 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 28 11:30:51 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Policy set 'Conexión cableada 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 28 11:30:51 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 11:30:51 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Apr 28 11:31:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 28 11:31:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 28 11:31:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 28 11:31:11 pakete207-G580 NetworkManager[995]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$
```

update of the last steps performed (note I had to delete some links becuase I can not add more than 2, instead of http// should be http://)

```
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
[sudo] password for pakete207: 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
build-essential ya está en su versión más reciente.
linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic ya está en su versión más reciente.
linux-headers-generic ya está en su versión más reciente.
El paquete indicado a continuación se instaló de forma automática y ya no es necesarios.
  linux-image-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 8 no actualizados.

pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$ wget -O- http//linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2 | tar -xj
```

--2013-04-29 17:14:48--  http//linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2
    Resolviendo linuxwireless.org (linuxwireless.org)... 78.46.109.217
    Conectando con linuxwireless.org (linuxwireless.org)[78.46.109.217]:80... conectado.
    Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 301 Moved Permanently
    Ubicación: http//wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2 [siguiente]
    --2013-04-29 17:14:48--  http//wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2
    Resolviendo wireless.kernel.org (wireless.kernel.org)... 144.76.43.152
    Conectando con wireless.kernel.org (wireless.kernel.org)[144.76.43.152]:80... conectado.
    Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
    Longitud: 4650013 (4,4M) [application/octet-stream]
    Grabando a: “STDOUT”

```
100%[======================================>] 4.650.013   1,55MB/s   en 2,9s   

2013-04-29 17:14:51 (1,55 MB/s) - escritos a stdout [4650013/4650013]


pakete207@pakete207-G580:~$ cd compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc

pakete207@pakete207-G580:~/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc$ ./scripts/driver-select alx
Processing new driver-select request...
Backing up makefile: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/Makefile.bk

pakete207@pakete207-G580:~/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc$ make
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh /home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/.config /home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/config.mk > include/linux/compat_autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc modules
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic»
  CC [M]  /home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/compat/main.o
  LD [M]  /home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/compat/compat.o
  CC [M]  /home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.o
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c: En la función ‘alx_hw_printk’:
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:124:3: error: declaración implícita de la función ‘__netdev_printk’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c: En el nivel principal:
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1955:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_init_adapter_special’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:2010:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_init_adapter’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3472:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_init’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3780:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_remove’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3903:17: error: ‘alx_init’ no se declaró aquí (no en una función)
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3904:2: error: declaración implícita de la función ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3904:29: error: ‘alx_remove’ no se declaró aquí (no en una función)
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:135:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_validate_mac_addr’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:210:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_init_hw_callbacks’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1698:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_alloc_all_rtx_queue’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1757:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_free_all_rtx_queue’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1773:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_set_interrupt_param’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1824:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_reset_interrupt_param’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1914:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_set_interrupt_mode’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1941:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_reset_interrupt_mode’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:2125:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_set_register_info_special’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3043:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_timer_routine’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3064:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_task_routine’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
cc1: algunos avisos se tratan como errores
make[4]: *** [/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic»
make: *** [modules] Error 2

pakete207@pakete207-G580:~/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc$ sudo make install
Updating Ubuntu's initramfs for 3.8.0-19-generic under /boot/ ...
Will now run update-grub to ensure grub will find the new initramfs ...
Generando grub.cfg ...
Se encontró una imagen linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Se encontró una imagen initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Encontrado en Windows Recovery Environment (loader) en /dev/sda3
Encontrado en Windows 8 (loader) en /dev/sda5
hecho

make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc modules
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic»
  CC [M]  /home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.o
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c: En la función ‘alx_hw_printk’:
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:124:3: error: declaración implícita de la función ‘__netdev_printk’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c: En el nivel principal:
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1955:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_init_adapter_special’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:2010:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_init_adapter’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3472:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_init’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3780:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘alx_remove’
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3903:17: error: ‘alx_init’ no se declaró aquí (no en una función)
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3904:2: error: declaración implícita de la función ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3904:29: error: ‘alx_remove’ no se declaró aquí (no en una función)
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:135:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_validate_mac_addr’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:210:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_init_hw_callbacks’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1698:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_alloc_all_rtx_queue’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1757:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_free_all_rtx_queue’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1773:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_set_interrupt_param’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1824:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_reset_interrupt_param’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1914:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_set_interrupt_mode’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:1941:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_reset_interrupt_mode’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:2125:12: aviso: se define ‘alx_set_register_info_special’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3043:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_timer_routine’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.c:3064:13: aviso: se define ‘alx_task_routine’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-function]
cc1: algunos avisos se tratan como errores
```

make[4]: *** [/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx_main.o] Error 1
    make[3]:**  [/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx] Error 2
    make[2]:  **[/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [*module*/home/pakete207/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc] Error 2
    make[1]: se sale del directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic»
    make: *** [modules] Error 2

```
pakete207@pakete207-G580:~/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc$
```

Comment: Is the Android hotspot set up with the same authentication/encyption settings than your domestic network?

Comment: The hotspot is set with WPA2 PSK, and the domestic network with WPA2 (AES), but I have tried to remove the password and there's no way :_(  Do you need any additional data? if you need something, please ask. I'm quite novice, but I'll try my best.

Comment: Let´s run a test: connect to the Android hotspot and then run 'grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | tail -30' in terminal. Then connect to your home WiFi and run the same command. Then edit your question adding the output of both commands.

Comment: I've run the tests, the results are on my first question. thanks for your time!

Comment: For the case of your domestic network via WiFi, seems authentication and encryption is detected fine but some steps still missing after it. Please try again to connect and then run 'grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | tail -60' in order to get more lines from syslog and see if they give us useful information.

Comment: updated! just ask if you need more lines, or any other info.

Comment: According to your last update, seems there is no problem in the wireless layer, as asssociation to the wireless network gets completed and network manager progresses to the next step: ip configuration via DHCP. I would check in your router (or DHCP server) if DHCP request is received and progressed when you try to connect the laptop to the wifi network.

Comment: sorry to ask, but i'm quite newbie.. could please tell me how to check in my router if DHCP request is received and progressed?

Comment: i was thinking, is it because my card is not recognised by Ubuntu? maybe the problem will be solved if I change the card for the card on my old computer (in which wifi was working properly).  Do you think that it may be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Running the following commands worked for me on Lenovo G580:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
wget -O- http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2 | tar -xj
cd compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks Vercevales, I have tried your solution, but no luck.  I have updted my post with the results obtained, maybe there's an error and you can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. The Android hot spot is without any security, so I changed my home wireless router to non-encrypted and now my laptop works!!!

I used the suggestion from  Daniel Yuste Aroca and I saw that there is a problem with DHCP. So I assigned a static IP address to my laptop and now it works with security enabled.

So it seams that DHCP isn't working with security enabled.

I tried also the suggestion fron another user and disabled the proprietary drivers. It works with DHCP and security enabled.

A little summary for me:
- Proprietary drivers: It works with DHCP and no-security or with static IP and security enabled
- Ubuntu driver: It works with DHCP and security enabled

Andrea

Comment: I have even tried removing the password from the router, it tries to connect, but it keeps trying for a minute or so, and then it stops and says I have no internet connection..

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable 3rd party drivers. It works for me.
Piotr

Comment: I'm using at the moment the private one. Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA from bcmwl-kernel-source. i will try to change it and reboot the pc, and i will tell you, thanks Piotr!

Comment: ops! even worse, when i disabled it, it doesn't even recognise the networks available.  I can not even see them, when i enabled it again, i can see them, but not connect to them